# Use of Action hook in wordpress to prepopulate form field

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm new to wordpress actions and i'm trying two things.

- I'm tying to output the data based on a action hook.
  The documentation of the plugin only says the following:
  ***6. Action eideasy_user_identified. Runs immediately after user data has been received and includes array of data returned by eID Easy.***

Does anybody has a tip on how to output this data?

And even better how to use the output from this data to prepopulate form fields from another wordpress plugin.

I realy hope someone can help me or give me a example to get started.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin in the picture is [eID Easy](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-id/)

Here's how you can log the data in a file:

**Step 1:** Create a file called log.txt
**Step 2:** Create a file called eid-log.php

Put the below code in the eid-log.php file:

```
<?php
/**
* eID LOG
*
* @package eID LOG
* @author Vinay
* @license gplv2-or-later
* @version 1.0.0
*
* @wordpress-plugin
* Plugin Name: eID LOG
* Plugin URI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73491338/use-of-action-hook-in-wordpress-to-prepopulate-form-field
* Description: Log the eID data in a file
* Version: 1.0.0
* Author: Vinay Jain
* Author URI: https://stackoverflow.com/users/17995563/vinay-jain
* Text Domain: eid-log
* Domain Path: /languages
* License: GPLv2 or later
* License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with Hot Recipes. If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html/>.
*/

add_action('eideasy_user_identified', 'eid_log_to_file', 10, 1);
function eid_log_to_file($result){
    if (!is_null($result)) {
        $myfile = fopen(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."log.txt", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, "==================================");
        fwrite($myfile, print_r($result, true));
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Zip both the files and name it eid-log.zip, then go to Wp-admin > Plugins > Add new > Upload

**Step 4.** Activate the plugin and then use your eID Easy plugin.

**Step 5:** Read the log.txt file for the data.

This will log each entry in the log.txt file. This should work, if not then let me know.

Comment: I will test it asap ... I have one more question.. do you think it's possible to only redirect to a page after login when a specific city is on the id?if it's not the right city, they should not be redirected..  Actually the same as a age verification  but than based on the adress.

Comment: I couldn't get this thing "city on id". Can you elaborate better?

Comment: The website i'm using has to check if a customer lives in a particular city before he gets redirected.
Normally the residence is stored on the Id card. (I mean residence with city)

Comment: You need to post a separate question for that. The resolution to this question seems to be done with my answer so you can accept this one and post a new question and I'll solve that for you there.

Comment: Ok thank you.. 
I've posted a new question. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73498938/eideasy-plugin-question-redirect-based-on-value)